# Joomla. Where article is outputed?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I'm new in Joomla and so need some help with basic.
I have write template for Joomla 1.7 and use it in such way:

Template have one position called "main".

I use custom HTML for building page structure and include modules with ModulesAnywhere plugin.
Now I have module which list all articles from category. When I click on the link I am redirecting to my_site/category/article_name. But where article text is outputed?

It seems like that it should be ouptuted in  position. If so how could I dynamicly add this tag in my custom HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The articles are showed by default (or any other component content)where this tag is located in your template:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Normal content does not require any position like modules.

Comment: Ok. Thats clear, thanks. Is there any ways to place this tag in my custom html? I mean, could I create some kind of module which will contain this tag and place it in places where i prefer?

Comment: Yeah. I try Sourcer module which able to write my own php or html. It seems that they work after tag processing